# Multiply pandas series by dictionary values

Tags: python

I have a pandas series

```
A    3
B    5
```

and a dictionary

```
dic={'A':4 , 'B':3}
```

I wanted to match and multiply this series by a dictionary and its values.

So the outcome is

```
A    12
B    15
```

Is this possible?

I've tried

```
s=s.mul(s.map(dic))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make a `Series` out of your dictionary and you can multiply it straightforward

```
s1 = pd.Series({'A':3 , 'B':5})
s2 = pd.Series({'A':4 , 'B':3})

s3 = s1*s2
print(s3)

A    12
B    15
dtype: int64
```

Depending on what you want to achieve, this function may also help.

```
def multiply(series, dictionary):
    r = {}
    for k in series.keys():
        if k in dictionary:
            r[k] = series[k] * dictionary[k]

    return pd.Series(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it if you convert your pandas input series into a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'b': [5,4,3,3,4],
    'c': [3,2,4,3,10],
    'd': [3, 2, 1, 1, 1]
})
params = {'a': 2.5, 'b': 3.0, 'c': 1.3, 'd': 0.9}

df1 = df.assign(**params).mul(df)
```